# How to sum data in a column corresponding to a start date to today's date

Tags: excel, vlookup

So, I am working on a loan payoff sheet and I wanted my excel sheet to be automatically updating.

One of my questions was answered when I searched how to select data corresponding to today's date using the function `VLOOKUP(TODAY(),A:B,2,0)` but that will only respond data in the column adjacent to today's date.

I would like to sum the data in the column of daily interest from the start date (provided) and have it automatically update for today's date. Attached is a snapshot of what I am trying to describe.

[image: Loan example image]

I currently have the dates stretched out several months in the future and am just summing the entire column of daily interest values.

If anyone knows how I can choose a start date of the first day and then automatically sum the values of the dates in between that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Column A is your Date column and its the only numbers in the column you can use:

```
=MIN(A:A)
```

Having said that normally charts like this are built by a start date provided in a cell somewhere.  If you can find that cell, simply link to it instead.

In order to get your sum of only appropriate dates, you will want to look at the formula  SUMIFS.  This will allow you to have multiple criteria that all have to be true.  Assuming your interest is in column C you might be able to use the following formula:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,">="&MIN(A:A),A:A,"<="&TODAY())
'Substitute your direct cell link for MIN(A:A) if you have it
```

Basically

```
=SUMIFS(Range to sum,  range to check 1, criteria for check 1, range to check 2, criteria for check 2)
```

If for some reason you have data above and below your dates and interest column, you may need to adjust your ranges from A:A to A5:A678 where 5 is the first row of your data and 678 is the last row of your data.

Answer (score 1):

With dates in column **A** and value in column **B**, place the start date in **C1** and the formula:

```
=TODAY()
```

in **C2**.  Then in another cell enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A9999<C2)*(A1:A9999>C1)*B1:B9999)
```

[image]

This formula give the sum of values **between** the date limits *(not including)*.

The formula does not require the dates in column **A** to be in sorted order.

Comment: FYI - I do not believe the `--`is required since the logic check is going through a math operation regardless.